# Is the diagonal morphism of schemes the result of a base change?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

In general, if $f : X \to Y$ is a morphism of schemes, then is it true that the diagonal morphism $\Delta : X \to X \times_Y X$ is the result of some base extension of $f$?

Specifically, I was onto the idea that, given $X \times_Y X$ is a scheme over $Y$, we might have that $X$ satisfies the universal fiber product properties with projections $id: X \to X$ and $\Delta : X \to X \times_Y X$. But working through the commutative diagrams, this doesn't appear to be the case unless I could assume e.g. $f$ is a monomorphism.

Comment: So you are asking whether there is a Cartesian diagram $$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X @>>> T\\
@V{\Delta}VV @VVV \\
X \times_Y X @>>> Y
\end{CD}$$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible in general. Let $Y = \operatorname{Spec} \mathbb Z$ be the final object.

If there were a cartesian diagram $$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD} X @>>> X\\ @V{\Delta}VV @V{f}VV \\ X \times_{Y} X @>>> \operatorname{Spec} \mathbb Z \end{CD}$$
we would have $$\operatorname{Hom}(-,X) = \operatorname{Hom}(-,X \times_{Y} X) \times \operatorname{Hom}(-,X) = \operatorname{Hom}(-,X) \times \operatorname{Hom}(-,X) \times \operatorname{Hom}(-,X)$$
, which is absurd for the most choices of $X$.

Comment: Sorry, I mean to ask whether there is a Cartesian diagram $$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD} X @>{\Delta}>> X \times_Y X\\ @VVV @V{g}VV \\ X @>{f}>> Y \end{CD}$$for some $g$.

Comment: Yes, and my example shows that this is not possible.

Comment: Actually I showed more, because I showed that it is not the base change of amy map to $Y$. But now I edited it to cover only the case of base extensions of $f$. Hopefully this clears things up.